# Difference in returning value by return statement and Enviroment.ExitCode

Tags: c#

I'm playing with return value from console and I saw some interesting. What differences came from:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = 4;
}
```

and

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    return 10;
}
```

?

If I use both:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.ExitCode = 4;
    return 10;
}
```

Then exit code:
in commandline it is always: 10,
in visual studio it is: 4,
from visual studio with disabled hosting process it is: 10.
**Question:**
What differs this two methods of setting exit code and which one is considered as most proffered to use?

Comment: From msdn, [Environment.ExitCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.exitcode.aspx) should be ignored in the third example because you have a non-`void` `Main`. So it is a problem of the vshost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the difference that "vshost.exe" makes in this scenario.

The `vshost.exe` processes launches the original executable using `Assembly.ExecuteAssembly()`, which in turn is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxx9f4c2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to "The value returned by the entry point of the assembly."

However, the (generated) Main-method of vshost.exe executables doesn't return int, but void. That is, it ignores the value returned by `ExecuteAssembly`.

For example, it does not look something/conceptually like this:

```
  class VsHost
  {
      public static int Main(string[] args) {
           // ...
           return appDomain.ExecuteAssembly("true.exe", ...);
      }
  }
```

But rather looks something like this:

```
  class VsHost
  {
      public static void Main(string[] args) {
           // ...
           appDomain.ExecuteAssembly("true.exe", ...);
           // Nothing here...
      }
  }
```

So, basically, when it exits, the only exit code that is set, is the one provided by `Environment.ExitCode` in the "real" executable. Mind you, that the `ExitCode` is global value, independent of the AppDomain it was set in.

You can easily test this behavior using your third example and the following "vshost-mock":

```
   // Compile to "Example3.exe"
   using System;
   class Example3
   {
       public static int Main(string[] args) {
           Environment.ExitCode = 4;
           return 5;
       }
   }

   // Complile to "VsHostMock.exe"
   using System;
   class VsHostMock
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args) {
          var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("other");
          int returnCode = appDomain.ExecuteAssembly("Example3.exe");
          Console.WriteLine("ReturnCode: {0}", returnCode);
          Console.WriteLine("Environment.ExitCode: {0}", Environment.ExitCode);
       }
   }
```

Then run the following:

```
   C:\> VsHostMock.exe ; echo %ERRORLEVEL%
   ReturnCode: 5
   Environment.ExitCode: 4
```

Then run:

```
   C:\> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
   4
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`Environment.ExitCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> If the Main method returns void, you can use this property to set the
>   exit code that will be returned to the calling environment. If Main
>   does not return void, this property is ignored. The initial value of
>   this property is zero.

So in your case, your `main` returns an `int` which means that `Environment.ExitCode` should not be used really (the documentation states it will be ignored apparently). If your `main` was returning `void` than it seems that `Environment.ExitCode` would behave as expected.

As you are using `Environment.ExitCode` with an `int main()` method, that might be throwing up weird results when you run with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft:

> If the Main method returns void, you can use this property to set the
>   exit code that will be returned to the calling environment. If Main
>   does not return void, this property is ignored. The initial value of
>   this property is zero.

Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

I personally prefer to use `return` from `Main`, but I guess as usual the choice would be entirely down to you.